# How to sum union query result?

Tags: mysql, sum, union

Helo,
i have worked query like this:

```
SELECT 
if (cf_1095-accountingpaidamount>0,FORMAT(cf_1095-accountingpaidamount, 0, 'de_DE'),0) as Kurang_Gesek

FROM vtiger_servicecontracts, vtiger_crmentity, vtiger_servicecontractscf, vtiger_campaign, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_accounting, vtiger_accounting_payments

WHERE
vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction=vtiger_accounting.accountingid
and
vtiger_accounting.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and
vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and
vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155
and vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and accountingtype="Pelunasan Gesek"
group by campaignname

UNION

SELECT 
if (cf_1095>0,FORMAT(cf_1095, 0, 'de_DE'),0) as Kurang_Gesek

FROM vtiger_servicecontracts, vtiger_crmentity, vtiger_servicecontractscf, vtiger_campaign, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_accounting, vtiger_accounting_payments

WHERE
vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction=vtiger_accounting.accountingid
and
vtiger_accounting.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and
vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and
vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155
and vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid

and accountingpaidamount=accountingamount

group by campaignname
having length(GROUP_CONCAT(accountingtype SEPARATOR " "))=12
```

What i am trying to reach is to display SUM Result of column Kurang_Gesek in  query above..

Can anyone help?

Thanks before...

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subquery:

```
select sum(Kurang_Gesek)
from (<your query here>) q
```

Comment: hi it run successfully but: the query above result is row 1 is 649000 and row 2 is13225500 but  using your subquery the result of sum is 662205. it should be 649000+13115500

Comment: This query should return one row with one column, which is the sum of the values in your column.

Comment: hey thankks.. it was my mistake... i format it before sum so it change the value. i want to vote u up but i am unable

Answer (score 0):

So just wrap your query with another `SELECT`:

```
SELECT t. *, SUM(t.Kurang_Gesek)
FROM (
SELECT
...
UNION
...
) t
GROUP BY t.some_column_you_need
```